# How can I get mock a method to only return an object once? (I am testing a pagination cursor)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to return a next_cursor one time. This code right now shoots me into an infinite loop when testing:

```
slack_client = double('slack_client')
slack_response = OpenStruct.new(response_metadata: OpenStruct.new(next_cursor: 'page-2'))
expect(slack_client).to receive(:users_list).and_return(slack_response)
```

The actual Slack method looks like this:

```
next_cursor = nil
loop do
    users_list_response = slack_client.users_list(cursor: next_cursor)

    # do real work in here...

    next_cursor = users_list_response.try(:response_metadata).try(:next_cursor)
    break if next_cursor.blank?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supply the different parameters as part of the mock:

```
expect(slack_client).to receive(:users_list).with(cursor: nil).and_return(slack_response_page_1)
expect(slack_client).to receive(:users_list).with(cursor: 'page-2').and_return(slack_response_page_2)
```

Comment: Woah! I didn't realize it was sequential like that. Thank u.

Comment: Yep, that's the general idea -- it's pagination!